# How to listen for snippet insertion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In vscode plugin development, is there a way to listen to the event when a code snippet is inserted? I want to perform some other operations when this event occurs.

For example, consider the following snippet:

```json
{
  "useCallback": {
      "key": "useCallback",
      "prefix": "useCallback",
      "body": [
          "useCallback(() => {",
          "  ${1}",
          "}, [${2}])"
      ]
  }
}
```

I would like to receive a notification through a hook or some other mechanism when this snippet is inserted, so that I can dynamically insert an import statement at the top of the file using the plugin API, like:

`import { useCallback } from 'react'`

Comment: create a `CompletionItemProvider` that inserts the snippet, the provider must not supply the completion at the `provide` call but wait for the `resolve` call. you have no feedback when the snippet ends, so you might insert the text before the snippet